texlive miktex conflict - texhash
I'm working with Ubuntu 22.04 and texlive (I'm using the Ubuntu texlive from tug.org). I tried to install miktex but gave up because I could not finalize the installation of the miktex console, which would have allowed me to finalize the complete installation. Since I uninstalled miktex, the texhash command no longer works.

sudo texhash

the terminal answers me:

texhash: error while loading shared libraries: libmiktex-setup.so.6:
cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

However, I uninstalled miktex using the dedicated page and reinstalled texlive.

I just deleted the path

:/usr/bin

but the same error message responded to me from the terminal when I run the texhash command and the return of type -all texhash :

texhash is /usr/local/bin/texhash texhash is /usr/bin/texhash texhash
is /bin/texhash texhash is
/usr/local/texlive/2024/bin/x86_64-linux/texhash

Do you have an idea?

Welcome to TeX.SE!

well it looks as if you did not completly deinstalled miktex as its texhash is still found.

On installing texlive from tug you should have put the texlive bin directory, most likely
/usr/local/texlive/2024/bin/x86_64-linux

at the front of your PATH.
If you have done that it makes no difference if miktex is installed or not, the texlive one will be used.
On the commandline type
type -all texhash

it will  list the found versions eg I get
$ type -all texhash
texhash is /usr/local/texlive/2024/bin/x86_64-linux/texhash
texhash is /usr/bin/texhash
texhash is /bin/texhash

showing I'm using tl2024 but have unused ubuntu provided tex further down the PATH in /usr/bin
